# Order column chart by count ID

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I have data on neighbourhood complaints regarding dogs, noise, garbage etc. I'm trying to visualize with a column chart. The neighbourhoods on the x-axis have to be ordered by the count (occurences) on the y-axis.

Alfabetical ordering is default, but I do not know how to change it. I've tried to sort neighboudhood by ID, but this doesn't work.

No code is used as this was produced in the Dashboard module.

The result should include a column chart, ordering neighbourhoods by the number of complaints in a descending order.

Who can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at my 11.1.4 dashboard chart with Product line on the X axis and Revenue on the Y axis.  If I sort on Revenue the chart displays in the correct order.  What happens when you sort the Number of Occurrences field in your chart?